# Need help on MYSQL QUERY (SUM)

Tags: mysql, select

I need some help from you with a SELECT QUERY. I just wanted to sum correctly the following table. The table is a synthese from several other tables. I probably will add an id int value for student's name instead of text to make it easier to goup - but this is not my problem.

I want to sum for each student the three types of absent lessons. But with my sql I got only one each time! What am I doing wrong? I tried several changes but I didn't find it out..

I wanted to add a screen from my mysql table but I don't have enough reputation..

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( P.synthese_abs_schueler_name ) AS synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                SUM(A.synthese_sum)              AS absent, 
                SUM(B.synthese_sum)              AS nonexcused, 
                SUM(C.synthese_sum)              AS tardive, 
                SUM(absent + nonexcused)         AS totalabs, 
FROM   synthese_abs AS P 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 1 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0 
                  GROUP  BY synthese_abs_schueler_name) AS A 
              ON A.synthese_abs_type = P.synthese_abs_type 
                 AND A.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 2 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0 
                  GROUP  BY synthese_abs_schueler_name) AS B 
              ON B.synthese_abs_type = P.synthese_abs_type 
                 AND B.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 3 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0 
                  GROUP  BY synthese_abs_schueler_name) AS C 
              ON C.synthese_abs_type = P.synthese_abs_type 
                 AND C.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
ORDER  BY P.synthese_abs_schueler_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as below instead of using many self joins ,you can use `CASE` in `SUM()` to sum `synthese_sum` based on values of `synthese_abs_type` and for the grand sum of absent and nonexcused i have used a subselect because at the same level of query you can use the alias of aggregate result in select either use sub select or repeat whole expression

```
SELECT *, absent + nonexcused  AS totalabs
FROM (
SELECT  synthese_abs_schueler_name ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN synthese_abs_type = 1 THEN synthese_sum ELSE 0 END) AS absent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN synthese_abs_type = 2 THEN synthese_sum ELSE 0 END) AS nonexcused,
    SUM(CASE WHEN synthese_abs_type = 3 THEN synthese_sum ELSE 0 END)  AS tardive
FROM 
synthese_abs 
WHERE synthese_abs_sum >0 
GROUP BY synthese_abs_schueler_name 
ORDER BY synthese_abs_schueler_name 
) t
```

Comment: This is it!!!! Thank you a lot. Fine - your query is really much cleaner than mine was. I have to do some work on my sql-queries seeing this clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the GROUP BY clause in the three sub queries you have and adding it to the main query:

```
SELECT P.synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                SUM(A.synthese_sum)              AS absent, 
                SUM(B.synthese_sum)              AS nonexcused, 
                SUM(C.synthese_sum)              AS tardive, 
                SUM(absent + nonexcused)         AS totalabs, 
FROM   synthese_abs AS P 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 1 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0) AS A 
              ON A.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 2 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0 ) AS B 
              ON B.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT synthese_abs_schueler_name, 
                         synthese_abs_type, 
                         synthese_abs_sum AS synthese_sum 
                  FROM   synthese_abs 
                  WHERE  synthese_abs_type = 3 
                         AND synthese_abs_sum > 0) AS C 
              ON C.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name 
GROUP  BY P.synthese_abs_schueler_name
```

Comment: This was a good hint. Even with this I don't have all students separated. Is it possible that it shows only the student who has an entry in every three categories? LEFT JOIN should give me NULL if there is no entry and not ignore it completely?

Comment: **@Ameliore**, I edited my answer.  Does that give you what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.synthese_abs_schueler_name AS synthese_abs_schueler_name,
    SUM(A.synthese_abs_sum) AS absent,
    SUM(B.synthese_abs_sum) AS nonexcused,
    SUM(C.synthese_abs_sum) AS tardive,
    SUM(A.synthese_abs_sum)+SUM(B.synthese_abs_sum) AS totalabs
FROM 
synthese_abs AS P

LEFT JOIN synthese_abs A ON A.synthese_abs_type = 1 AND A.synthese_abs_sum >0 AND A.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name

LEFT JOIN synthese_abs B ON B.synthese_abs_type = 2 AND B.synthese_abs_sum >0 AND B.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name

LEFT JOIN synthese_abs C ON C.synthese_abs_type = 3 AND C.synthese_abs_sum >0 AND C.synthese_abs_schueler_name = P.synthese_abs_schueler_name

GROUP BY P.synthese_abs_schueler_name
```

Basically, it's important you GROUP BY the name of the Schüler to get a sum *per Schüler*.

Comment: That one can't be executed - error. I found out that I have to group at the last line of the code. .. will try several things to find out how exaclty.

Comment: Edited the SQL, please have a look.